# How to bind input radio value to object in angular?

Tags: angular, html, frontend

I want to bind radio buttons with objects instead of strings. For that I tried a similar code to the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <input type="radio" id="category" [(ngValue)]="object">
</div>
```

Is there a way in Angular to bind objects with the values of radio buttons ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ngValue` won't be available for radio buttons. It's only available with `select` lists.

You can use the `[value]` attribute binding syntax to assign an object as the value of the selected radio button.

Use this for your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects">
  <input 
    (change)="onCheck()" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" 
    type="radio" 
    id="category" 
    [value]="object">
    {{ object.categoryValue }}
</div>
```

And in your Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  selectedCategory;

  objects = [
    {categoryName: 'Category1', categoryValue: 'Category1'},
    {categoryName: 'Category2', categoryValue: 'Category2'},
    {categoryName: 'Category3', categoryValue: 'Category3'},
  ];

  onCheck() {
    console.log(this.selectedCategory);
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9hkyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: One of the best explanations I came accross, thanks. Works like a charm in Angular 17+